# Using Hash Table in HTTP request

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I'm expected to write a c++ console application which reads text file consists of HTTP request to a web server and insert it in suitable data structure. I have to consider time efficiency as well. After reading and processing is over, my program should list the top 10 visited web pages.
So, I have decided to use hash tables and my question is what should be the way that I should follow once I insert the names into the hash table? What is the proper function to do this? Or where can I get the algorithm at least to have an idea?

Comment: Take it one step at a time, first make a c++ console application to read a text file and display the text. Babysteps are key for me. But try to work on this a bit and then post some code, most people could vote this down because it sounds like homework.

Comment: İ wrote the part of the code consists of reading the text file and displaying it

Comment: Ok so you then want to use a hash table to store the data. First you need to generate a hashkey for each item you want to add, this will be the index in the hashtable you add the data. Here is an example in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) but you can get the idea, the second parameter is the hashkey (aka the index where to add the data in the table). I personally think of a hashtable as an "array of linked lists".

Comment: Ok. After do this, how should I get filenames to insert them hash table? I mean with their ASCII code or any other efficient way ?

Comment: You said you wrote the part of the code that reads the text file. That is where you get the file names no?

Comment: There is misunderstanding, sorry. İ did mean i wrote the fstream part. İ cannot decide with respect to what I should get the strings?

Comment: that sounds like a question for your teacher, you need to speak with them to understand the assignment and what they mean. We can only really help with the technical part of it.

Comment: He told us nothing when we asked, but i really thank you. The example you share will be helpful.